# What would be blocking a CDN-downloaded script from executing in IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cdn

I have an HTML document (see below) that works fine in IE9, Chrome, etc, but in IE10, on some machines, fails with the error "$ not defined".  This indicates that jQuery is not being loaded.  However F12 tools on a problem machine reveals that the jquery *is* being downloaded to the browser (I get a 200 response, and the jquery code is in the response body).  If I use the same version jQuery loaded from the same server as the HTML document, it works, further implicating the CDN as a factor. IE ESC is off.  Antivirus is on the machines, but is disabled (McAfee). F12 tools show it's running in IE10 Compat View, Standards mode.  Changing modes has no effect.

In this case I can do a local fallback, but in cases where I don't control the markup, and just in general, I'd like to know what is blocking this from running.

This is in a large enterprise, and there are group policy customizations, but I can't find anything in IE settings that looks "off". Are there specific IE settings or other things that would cause this behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#cmdTest').click(function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
});
</script>

<title>CDN Example</title>


</head>

<body>
This is an example of broken CDN. You should see an alert when you click the button below.
<button id="cmdTest">Test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are running this on a webserver when it fails(it will not work on local filesystem)

Comment: I have noticed similar when attempting to include a dynamic js script on a page from a different domain. Whether I make the request with a script tag or by building it w/ js (jquery or vanilla).. the js will execute. But the problem came from attempting to set and read cookies in the server-side script and then set and output js values. The js was executed but with no value being set. I discovered this was some kind of security issue with new IE versions.. the default security/privacy settings prevented the remote from setting 3rd party cookies. I don't know if this is your full story but

Comment: that's what I found.. if i lowered my IE security/privacy settings to lowest, it accepted it. But that was a fail because I can't expect visitors to do that.. in any case, perhaps your problem is the same or related. try lowering IE's security/privacy settings and see if it works

Comment: I tried, using "codepen", with IE11 without any problem

Comment: I lowered privacy to "All cookies" and Security to "low", and still get the same behavior.

Comment: I am running it on a webserver, not filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"`?  Your code didn't work for me anywhere until I added the `http://`.  Then it worked in both IE and Chrome

Comment: Using `//` without the `http` (or `https`) tells the browser to use the same protocol as the page currently is on.  It's used so you don't have to make separate pages for http/https.  I'm (not at all) surprised that it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: i've never had issue with IE or any browser not accepting use of `//` without `http` or `https` ?

Comment: Yeah, I do that all the time, and it works in all browsers.  I tried it with http:// (since I'm on non-ssl here) and it did not work.